# Prolog beginner ERROR: Out of local stack

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I am very new to Prolog programming. Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have the following program,

```
bigger(elephant, horse).
bigger(horse, donkey).
bigger(donkey, dog).
bigger(donkey, monkey).

is_bigger(X, Y) :- bigger(X, Y).
is_bigger(X, Y) :- is_bigger(Z, Y), bigger(X,Z).
```

On running the query,

```
?- is_bigger(A, donkey)
```

I get the following output,

```
A = horse ;
A = elephant ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

While I do somewhat understand how A = horse and A = elephant, I am having a difficult time understanding why it's recursing infinitely (I used the builtin trace *trace* predicate but couldn't understand it after *A = elephant*).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_bigger(X, Y) :- is_bigger(Z, Y), bigger(X,Z).
```

The above line is the one causing the out of local stack message. You're calling "is_bigger" again which calls "is_bigger" again and so on, recursively

---

Your input:  `is_bigger(A, donkey)`

First, you want to find something that is bigger than the donkey or/and something that is bigger than the thing that's bigger than the donkey.

Therefore:

```
is_bigger(X, Y) :- bigger(Z, Y), bigger(X,Z).
```

Why?

Y binds to donkey.

Z bind to horse.

As a last step, you're looking for `bigger(X, horse)`

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the recursion is the whole point, since we want to be able to detect chains longer than 2, i.e. something that is bigger than something that is bigger than ... that is bigger than a donkey.  If we also had `bigger(whale, elephant).` then your approach would not agree that `is_bigger(whale, donkey)`.

Comment: In that case:
is_bigger(X, Y) :- bigger(Z, Y), is_bigger(X,Z).

Comment: The reason it doesn't work when you put is_bigger first, is because it will keep looping trying to find is_bigger(Z,Y). But if you put it last, it will have found all animals in bigger(Z,Y) already, which then can be recursed/matched through in Z in the last is_bigger(X,Z).

Comment: @programmingwat could you update your answer with the proper recursive solution so we can upvote it?